# Why are the O'Brien family quarters on the Enterprise-D so small?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwx5uB0pyhQ), Lt. Cdr. La-Forge's quarters are 28 m<sup>2</sup>, while the O'Briens' family quarters are 32 m<sup>2</sup>. Why does a family of 3 get such small quarters? Is it because O'Brien is a petty officer rather than a regular officer?

Comment: LaForge is a fourth or fifth in command of a 1000-person vessel.  O'Brien is enlisted.   I don't think this requires much explanation.

Comment: The real question is why the top crew members only get thirty-something square meters, when estimates based on the blueprints suggest that the ship has about 800,000 square meters of space. If a mere tenth of that space is available for crew due to equipment constraints, ventilation—and what is shown of equipment areas suggests that is conservative—it seems that people should have an *average* of around 30 square meters (with approximately 3000 crew).

Comment: @Adamant there's about 1000 crew and their family members. But there's hallways, community spaces (10-Forward), holodecks, cargo storage, service ducts, and engineering spaces to fit in, too.

Comment: There's also space to allow the ship to transport colonists and evacuate casualties from major disasters.

Comment: @Adamant - This is also a Starfleet vessel. If everyone of the 1024 crew got 100 meters of room, it wouldn't be fair to other people in the same fleet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134756/discussion-on-question-by-einpoklum-why-are-the-obrien-family-quarters-on-the-e).

Answer (score 6):

According to the *[Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)*, each person aboard the Enterprise is assigned approximately 110 square metres of personal living quarters space, over three times as much as was stated in that YouTube video.

> 13.4 CREW QUARTERS SYSTEMS
>
> Starfleet believes that providing comfortable living quarters to all crew and attached personnel to be of primary importance. Indeed, living accommodations are one of the most visible displays of Starfleet's commitment to caring for its single most important "system," its people.
>
> **Each person aboard the *Enterprise* is assigned approximately 110 square meters of personal living quarters space.** These accommodations typically include a bedroom, living work area, and a small bathroom. **Families may request that their living quarters be combined to create a single larger dwelling.** Living quarters decks are designed to be modular with movable walls to permit reconfiguration for such requests as crew load and structure change.
>
> Other amenities available include food synthesizer terminals, sonic showers, standard showers, null-grav sleeping chambers, personal holographic viewers, and provisions for pets.
>
> Individuals assigned to the *Enterprise* for periods more than six months are permitted to reconfigure their quarters within hardware, mass, and volume limits. Individuals assigned for shorter periods are generally restricted to standard quarters configurations.
>
> [image]

There's artwork on the same page depicting what are described as "typical crew living accommodations" with an angled ceiling and vertical windows, such as those seen in the quarters of Picard, Riker, Crusher, and Troi. It's stated that the same five-room set is redressed to serve as the living quarters of "most of our regular characters", which suggests that the same set is used for all the characters named above.

> ***Most of the living quarters seen on the show feature an angled ceiling into which are set several vertical windows, through which one can see the stars.** These windows match those seen on the upper surface of the ship's Saucer Module. Since there are many hundreds of such windows on the* Enterprise *miniature, there are presumably hundreds of such living units on board the ship. **The same five-room set is redressed with different furniture and divided up in different ways to serve as the living quarters of most of our regular characters.***

The page also mentions another set, without windows, used for the quarters of junior officers. This was apparently a revamped version of the set used for Captain Kirk's quarters in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*.

> *We also have a "junior officers' quarters" set, which does not have the dramatic ceiling windows. This set was originally built as Captain Kirk's quarters for the furst* Star Trek *movie, and would seem to suggest that Starfleet has indeed upgraded its crew accommodations in the years between Kirk and Picard.*

The living quarters of characters such as Data, Geordi, Worf, and O'Brien look very different to the ones occupied by Picard, Riker, Crusher, and Troi, and are more in line with the description of the junior officers' quarters set.

The manual isn't too clear as to whether the figure of 110 square metres applies only to the larger quarters, or whether this is an average figure for all the quarters on the ship. By the sounds of it though, there are no quarters purpose-built for families. Rather, families either share a single unit, or they can request that two units be combined to form a larger dwelling.

From what we see of the O'Briens' quarters, they appear to live within a single unit of standard size for junior officers, rather than two units combined. Whether they didn't request to have two units combined, or whether such a request was denied for whatever reason, isn't something that's answerable with canon information, as far as I know.

It doesn't seem likely that O'Brien being enlisted was a factor, given that his quarters appear to be roughly the same size as those of Data, Geordi, and Worf. Also, Crusher and Worf both appear to share a single unit (albeit, of different sizes) with their sons, which might suggest that the combining of two units wasn't that common in practice.

Comment: "each person...  is assigned approximately 110 m^2 of ... quarters" <- Umm... if you watch TNG, it's obvious that nobody has quarters which are anywhere near that size, except for Captain Picard, and even his are probably not that big.

Comment: damn! 110m2 that's huge.

Comment: @Max Yes 110 m^2 is about 1200 ft^2 that's the sized of your typical mobile home. (15x80) That's enough space for a Living room, Kitchen, Dining room, Utility room (laundry), 2-3 bedrooms, and 1-2 bathrooms. I CAN see that much space devoted to the Captains Quarters. But, that is too much space for a typical crewman, or officer, even senior ones. They must not have properly done the math when they did the manual.  OR Many more of the crew are living about with families. IF everyone had a wife, and 2-3 kids, THEN I could see 110 m^2 being the typical quarters size.

Comment: @NJohnny - taking into account that, according to EC Henry's calculations at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwx5uB0pyhQ , there's over 600k sq.m. available for crew quarters in the saucer alone, 110 per person is not an unreasonable number. Certainly the justification quoted - long-term missions require spacious quarters for crew for minimum of well-being - is valid. I agree it's preposterous, though. Then again, since we know junior officers and junior enlisted share quarters, apartments of about 80-100 sq.m. are reasonable. Remember, Starfleet is not military, Enterprise is not a warship.